# Handsontable numeric cell globalization

Tags: globalization, handsontable

I'm relatively new to js and now have to implement a handsontable into our project.
This worked well so far, but I am hitting a roadblock with globalization.
Basically, we use comma as a decimal seperator, but when I try and copy something like "100,2" into a cell designated as 'numeric,' it will show as 1002.
If the same value is entered in a cell designated as 'text' and the type is changed to numeric afterwards, the value will be shown correctly.
For this I already had to add 'de' culture to the table sourcecode.(basically copying 'en' and changing the values currently relevant to me.)

```
    numeral.language('de', {
    delimiters: {
        thousands: '.',
        decimal: ','
    },//other non-relevant stuff here
```

When I copy the values directly from the table and insert them to np++ they show as 100.2 etc. However, when inserting them into handsontable the arguments-array looks as follows:

```
[Array[1], "paste", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
    0: Array[4]
        0: 1       //row
        1: 1       //column
        2: "100.2" //previous value
        3: 1002    //new value
```

Here's what I have tried currently:

```
    hot.addHook("beforeChange", function () {
    if (arguments[1] === "paste") {
        hot.updateSettings({
            cells: function (row, col, prop) {
                var cellProperties = {
                    type: 'numeric',
                    language: 'en'
                };
                return cellProperties;
            }
        });
        //hot.updateSettings({
        //    cells: function (row, col, prop) {
        //        var cellProperties = {
        //            type: 'text',
        //        };
        //        return cellProperties;
        //    }
        //});
    }
}, hot);

hot.addHook("afterChange", function () {
    if (arguments[1] === "paste") {
        ChangeMatrixSettings(); //reset cell properties of whole table
    }

}, hot);
```

I hope I've made my problem clear enough, not sure if I missed something.

Are there any other ways to get the correct values back into the table? Is this currently not possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked more than one thing, but let me see if I can help you.

As explained in [handsontable numeric documentation](http://handsontable.com/demo/numeric.html), you can define a format of the cell. If you want '100,2' to be shown you would format as follows

```
format: '0.,'
```

You can change that to what you really need, like if you are looking for money value you could do something like

```
 format: '0,0.00 $'
```

The other thing you asked about is not on the latest release, but you can check it out how it would work [here](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2060)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have since solved this problem via custom validation method and have posted an answer. Your solution works as well, but it does not completely cover the current needs I have for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have since implemented my own validation of input, due to other requirements we have for the table mainly in regards to showing invalid input to user.

```
function validateInputForNumeric(parameter) {
    var value = parameter[3];
    var row = parameter[0];
    var col = parameter[1];
    if (decimalSeperator === '') {
        var tmpculture = getCurrCulture();
    }

    if (value !== null && value !== "") {
        if (!value.match('([a-zA-Z])')) {
            if (value.indexOf(thousandSeperator) !== -1) {
                value = removeAndReplaceLast(value, thousandSeperator, ''); //Thousandseperators will be ignored
            }
            if (value.indexOf('.') !== -1 && decimalSeperator !== '.') {
                //Since numeric variables are handled as '12.3' this will customize the variables to fit with the current culture
                value = removeAndReplaceLast(value, '.', decimalSeperator);
            }
            //Add decimalseperator if string does not contain one
            if (numDecimalPlaces > 0 && value.indexOf(decimalSeperator) === -1) {
                value += decimalSeperator;
            }

            var index = value.indexOf(decimalSeperator)
            var zerosToAdd = numDecimalPlaces - (value.length - index - 1);
            for (var j = 0; j < zerosToAdd; j++) {
                //Add zeros until numberOfDecimalPlaces is matched for uniformity in display values
                value += '0';
            }
            if (index !== -1) {
                if (numDecimalPlaces === 0) {
                    //Remove decimalseperator when there are no decimal places
                    value = value.substring(0, index)
                } else {
                    //Cut values that have to many decimalplaces
                    value = value.substring(0, index + 1 + numDecimalPlaces);
                }
            }
            if (ErrorsInTable.indexOf([row, col]) !== -1) {
                RemoveCellFromErrorList(row, col);
            }

        } else {
            AddCellToErrorList(row, col);
        }
    }
    //console.log("r:" + row + " c:" + col + " v:" + value);
    return value;
}
```

The inputParameter is an array, due to handsontable hooks using arrays for edit-events. `parameter[2]` is the old value, should this be needed at any point.

This code works reasonably fast even when copying 2k records from Excel (2s-4s).
One of my main hindrances regarding execution speed was me using  the handsontable `.getDataAtCell` and `.setDataAtCell` methods to check. These don't seem to handle large tables very well ( not a critique, just an observation ). This was fixed by iterating through the data via `.getData` method.